# filter Data in Spring Boot Data REST

Tags: java, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot Data REST, yes, I write something like below:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ExerciseRepository extends JpaRepository<Exercise, Integer> {}
```

then I open `127.0.0.1/exercises`. It will show all exercises.
But I want only show some appointed exercises(eg. exercise id < 100, or other complicated logic) on the `127.0.0.1/exercises`.
I know I can use `@RestController`, but how can I do this with Spring Boot Data REST?

Comment: Maybe I need implements ExerciseRepository, then @Override findAll().

Comment: Do you want to filter by specific attribute or it should be dynamic?

Comment: by specific attribute, for example exercise id < 100.

Answer (score 0):

@RepositoryRestResource(path="exercises",collectionResourceRel = "exercises")

can you edit this according to your own code ? I think this will work for you

Comment: Thank you, I update my question make it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an interface method, for example:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ExerciseRepository extends JpaRepository<Exercise, Integer> {
    List<Exercise> findByIdLessThan(@Param("id") Integer id);
}
```

In this case, the query is derived from the method name directly, but you can also write a query manually using `@Query`, for more details check [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods).

To invoke the method use the following API request:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/exercises/search/findByIdLessThan?id=100
```

For reference, [Spring Data REST - Useful notes](https://gist.github.com/TomyJaya/31e48d81af0ca236496582d00192ef80).

---

EDIT:

If you use Hibernate as your persistence provider, you can use `@Where` for static filtering, and `@Filter` for dynamic filtering where filters are defined and configured at runtime, according to [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filtering).

For example, you can annotate the entity with `@Where` and define a condition that will be applied to all queries related to that entity:

```java
@Where(clause = "id<100")
@Entity
public  class Exercise{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I searched for a long time, it seems that only these two methods. Thank you very much.

Comment: I want filter data for all JpaRepository methods not only findAll. I want ExerciseRepository only handle exercises which exercise id < 100, (eg. findAll/findAllById/saveAll/deleteAllInBatch.. will only handle exercises which exercise id < 100). Maybe I need to override each methods.

Comment: @Tony.Luo I've updated the answer with a solution to apply a certain condition to all queries.